# How to show/convert datetime retrieved from API to a specific timezone

Tags: flutter, timezone

The PostgreSQL database shows: 2023-10-23 04:00:00.000 -0400.
The query has no formatting, just a simple column query.

The PHP API responds with a JSON showing: 2023-10-23 04:00:00+00.
On the PHP side there is no formatting as well, just a json encode on the resultset.

I'm trying to set the timezone in the main.dart like this.

```
Future<void> setSaoPauloTimezone() async {
    final Location location = tz.getLocation('America/Sao_Paulo');
    tz.setLocalLocation(location);
}
...
tzdata.initializeTimeZones();
await setSaoPauloTimezone();
```

The simplified model class:

```
class SGCard {
    final int id;
    final DateTime endDate;
    SGCard({
        required this.id,
        required this.endDate,
    });
    factory SGCard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return SGCard(
            id: json['id'],
            endDate: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').parse(json['end_date']),
        );
    }
}
```

And I try to show it with this:

```
...
cards[idx].endDate.toLocal().toString(),
...
```

It just does not work, it does not show the right date time according to America/SaoPaulo timezone.
I tried to use different AIs to help me, different formatting and a few different approaches but could not find a solution.

A little bit of help would be really appreciated.

I tried to use a few formatting patterns and set the timezone in different places in the code.

Comment: What timezone is the json string in?  That matters.  It looks like it's "+00", which is utc, but you didn't pass "true" for the utc parameter in .parse?

Comment: Good catch, I tried to add true to the parse function but it still not working though.

Comment: Show examples of the string and the parsed value.

Comment: just checked the php timezone and it is date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
I'm going to make both database and php set to 
'America/Sao_Paulo'. It might be not a flutter issue after all.